# Como puedo inicializar variables al regresar a una vista con Navigator.Pop en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Comunidad necesito ayuda, quiero saber como puedo volver a inicializar variables en una vista construida cuando se regresa a esta desde otra vista con el evento Navigator.Pop

Esta es mi vista donde se inicializa y desde donde se invoca a otra vista.

```
List<ListUserPaymentDestination>? listWallets = [];
List<ListUserPaymentDestination>? listBanks = [];
List<ListUserPaymentDestination>? listPaypals = [];
List<ListUserPaymentDestination>? listZelle = [];

class _ProfileScreen extends State<ProfilePaymentMethod> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    listWallets = g_listUserPaymentDestination
        .where((x) => x.order! == PaymenthWallet)
        .toList();
    listBanks = g_listUserPaymentDestination
        .where((x) => x.order! == Paymenthbank)
        .toList();
    listPaypals = g_listUserPaymentDestination
        .where((x) => x.order! == PaymentPaypal)
        .toList();
    listZelle = g_listUserPaymentDestination
        .where((x) => x.order! == PaymenthZelle)
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: _util.getColorFromHex("1e232f"),
```

Esta es la segunda vista que retornar a la primera a través de un Navigator.Pop

```
InkWell(
                  child: const widget_Retorno(Pagina: "Add Payment Methods"),
                  onTap: () {
                    final route = MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const ProfilePaymentMethod(),
                    );
                    Navigator.pop(context, route);
                  },
                ),
```

Lo que deseo es que al momento de regresar a la interfaz se vuelvan a cargar los elementos de las listas que están dentro del initState.

```
listWallets
listBanks
listPaypals
listZelle
```

muchas gracias.

Comment: consulta, por qué retornas el `route` en el Navigator.pop(context, aquí)? necesitas retornar un valor en especial?

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que esas `g_listUserPaymentDestination` son alguna data local.
En este caso para actualizar la data seria volver a asignar los valores en el resultado del future que nos regresa el `Navigator.push()`

```dart
Navigator.push(context, route).then((value){

 listWallets = g_listUserPaymentDestination......
 
 setState((){});

});
```

Algo asi seria para este caso.
Espero te sirva

Comment: Hola el problema es que esta pantalla tambien debe regresar a otra con un Navigator.Pop.

Comment: Solo que implementes un singleton, y asi guardas el dato que quieres sostener entre las Screens de la app

Comment: para evitar todo eso mira este video, para que aprendas la comunicación de widgets : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57CCj9UH_Gw

Answer (score 0):

Agrega lo que contiene el `initState` en otra función:

```
 inicializarListas(){
      listWallets = g_listUserPaymentDestination
        .where((x) => x.order! == PaymenthWallet)
        .toList();
    listBanks = g_listUserPaymentDestination
        .where((x) => x.order! == Paymenthbank)
        .toList();
    listPaypals = g_listUserPaymentDestination
        .where((x) => x.order! == PaymentPaypal)
        .toList();
    listZelle = g_listUserPaymentDestination
        .where((x) => x.order! == PaymenthZelle)
        .toList();
}
```

en el `initState` llama a la función que acabas de crear:

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    inicializarListas()
  }
```

Y en la propiedad donde navegas a la segunda pantalla pon esto:

```
await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
     (builder) => Pantalla a la que navegas)
     ).then((_) => setState(() {
      inicializarListas(); 
      }));
```